# What is the meaning of "extern PACKAGE TMyForm * MyForm"

Tags: c++, c++builder

In C++Builder XE2 the IDE will place this line of code in the header file associated with TMyForm immediately after the TMyForm class. I'm certain this relates to the the fact that all of the properties TMyForm are defined in MyForm.dfm and need to be linked into the executable somehow, but I can't find any reference to it in the documentation or online. Googling for "extern PACKAGE" just yields a lot of code samples that contain the phrase.

Strangely, commenting it out doesn't seem to have any effect. I even deleted the .res file and did a rebuild and the form works fine without it. Which seems to negate my assumption above.

Comment: It seems PACKAGE is a macro. Check for its definition.

Comment: @Mahesh I can't find a definition of it by right-clicking and choosing "find declaration", not sure where else to look.

Comment: `PACKAGE` is defined in sysmac.h.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`extern TMyForm *MyForm` is used to declare a global variable (which actually resides in your Form's .cpp file).  This variable points to your `TForm` object at runtime if it is configured to be auto-loaded at app startup, or if you assign it manually in your own code.

`PACKAGE` is a macro that expands to [`__declspec(package)`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Declspec%28package%29), which marks the class as being compilable in a Package, if you ever choose to use it inside of a Package.

Comment: Thanks Remy, I routinely remove the global declaration as I prefer to declare it where I use it, so I guess I can remove the extern declaration as well.